# Is there a way to test Eloquent Observers in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, testing, eloquent, phpunit

This is the problem I'm having:
My code is set in a way that whenever Model's X title gets updated, it should change Model Y's count.

So what I do is, i send request that will trigger the event described above, BUT whenever i check if the changes are made in the database, they are not.

I've tried dd() inside the X Observers updated function, and it gets properly fired.

Any ideas?

Edit: I'm testing with assertDatabaseHas()

Edit2: This is my code for the test

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $book = Book::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'name' => 'test'
    ]);

    $response = $this->getJson('/api/books-update?book_id=' . $book->id);

    $response->assertStatus(200);

    dd($response->getContent(), DB::table('books')->where('name', '=', 'JAJCA')->get());
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public function testEndpoint(Request $request)
{
    $book_id = $request->get('book_id');
    $book = Book::find($book_id);
    $book->update([
        'name' => 2
    ]);

    return response()->json($book, 200);
}
```

And this is the BookObserver@updated

```
public function updated(Book $book)
{
    $book->name = 'JAJCA';
}
```

The last line from TestBasicTest for getContent prints out:
`name => JAJCA` 
And for the `DB::table('books')->where('name', '=', 'JAJCA')->get()` returns empty array.

Comment: Could you show us the the code which is triggered in you updated hook ?

Comment: This is stackoverflow, here we need code to be able to help you and it is a requirement to show your process so far. How would we be able to help you withouth seing your implementation?

Comment: and what setting is your queue on when you test?

Comment: @mrhn I've updated my question with some code. Also, the queue is set to SYNC

Comment: Also, very weird thing is if I use UPDATING instead of UPDATED I get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated triggers after it has been saved. If you want to change input through events you will also have to use Updating and Creating.

So either use Updating like so, the save will happen after this event, with updated it has already happened.

```
public function updating(Book $book)
{
    $book->name = 'JAJCA';
}
```

Models are references so you are updating the object but not saving it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up! Very clear and precise answer!

Comment: The save comment was bad thou, as it would result in a stackoverflow triggering a new updated event.